# Interval of convergence of $\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^n x^n}{4^n \ln n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Hello I was wondering if anyone could help me with finding the interval of convergence for $x$ in this series.

I have put this through the standard ratio test which has given the result of the series converging for  $\left|\frac{x}{4}\right| < 1$. The ratio test does not tell me what happens when $\left|\frac{x}{4}\right|= 1$ however, so I've been trying to figure that out.

In this series however, the first term for any value of x is undefined so I don't understand how it can converge for any value of x, let alone 4 or -4. Could someone help me with testing convergence for those two values and explain why we can still test for convergence here despite there being an undefined term?

Comment: **Hint:** $x/4=\pm 1$ gives you the alternating series $$\pm \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n)}$$ Do you know any other series you can compare this to?

Comment: @K.defaoite You mean $x/4=1$. Then yes, alternating. Diverges for $x/4=-1$.

Comment: My apologies. Yes, in the case $x/4=-1$ it wont alternate.

Comment: You need to start with $n=2$.  $log(1)=0$.